# Access ListBox in class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listbox and in a separate class I'm trying to access the selected value of the listbox but it says it cannot be accessed as it is not public. I am also having the same problem with accessing a label.

```
 public dataCollector(string i)
    {
        string tag = i;
    }
    public string dataCollector()
    {
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        string workingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var xmlFile = XDocument.Load(workingDirectory + @"\modules.xml");

        var name = from d in xmlFile.Descendants("Name")
                   where d.Value == (String)f.selectionBox.SelectedItem
                   select d.Parent.Element(tag).Value;

        foreach (var item in name)
        {
            f.moduleName.Text = item.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Select the ListBox on your form and change the Modifier property from Private to Public.

This is happening because the Form Designer will create the Controls as Private by default. You can peek at the code generated by the Designer and see for yourself.

Example **Form1.Designer.cs** code...

```
partial class Form1
{
...
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
}
```

And after changing the Modifier property to public in the Designer...

```
partial class Form1
{
...
    public System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that solves my problem, do you know if I can get the value of item and return in from the method?

Comment: Welcome to SO, if it solves your issue please consider accepting it as the answer. Regarding your next/different question, if I understand you right, just look at @A. Rodas answer. He actually alludes to what I would argue is a more common solution to your scenario whereas I was providing the most direct answer to your issue at hand.

Comment: Not sure how to accept it and ok I will thanks to both for your help

Comment: See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and specifically [How to ask...](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)...